# Store Html.Raw() in a string in Javascript, ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET and I have a string of HTML in the database.

I want to get that html into a variable on the client.

If I do this:

```
var x = '@Html.Raw(myModel.FishValue)'
```

it works fine, because it's essentially doing

```
var x = '<p>hello!</p>';
```

however if there are quotes in the html it breaks the page.

My initial guess would be to .Replace the raw string to add escapes to the quotes, however both `.ToString()` and `.ToHtmlString()` (as Html.Raw returns an IHtmlString) do not produce the same markup as simple `Html.Raw()`.

So I'm at a loss of what best to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about replacing before calling the `Html.Raw`method?

```
 var x = '@Html.Raw(myModel.FishValue.Replace("'","\\'"))'
```

**UPDATE:**

There might be other escape chars in the string coming from the model. For that reason I would recommend replacing the slashes first as well. Of course it all depends on what might come from the server in your model.

```
 var x = '@Html.Raw(myModel.FishValue.Replace("\\","\\\\'").Replace("'","\\'"))'
```

A sample snippet representing the behavior in the javascript:

```js
//Let's say my Model Content is >  I'd Say \ is a escape character. You can't "Escape"  
    // YOu would have to replace ' --> \' and \ --> \\
    var stringFromServer = 'I\'d Say \\ is a escape character. You can\'t "Escape"'
    alert(stringFromServer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var x = '@(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myModel.FishValue))';
```

If you need to decode the HTML on the client side use

```
unescape(x)
```

I think JQuery (not sure if you're using it or not) handles encoded HTML strings so you might not need unescape().

Answer (score 1):

Try out the anti-xss library from Microsoft (which will be included I believe by default in asp.net 4.5):

```
 AntiXss.JavascriptEncode(yourContent)
```

Anti-Xss is available 4.1 beta. If you want to use it in your application which I highly recommend, check out:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/04/28/using-antixss-4-1-beta-as-the-default-encoder-in-asp-net.aspx